# Connecting audio line to ESP8266 / ESP32

Tags: audio, adc

I don't know how to correctly connect audio line to ADC input of ESP32 board. The audio line is common stereo output from phone, PC or audio mixer. I didn't find any schematic or advice how to do that for 3.3V ADC range. Do you have any idea or advice where is possible to find it out?

Comment: it goes to ADC and GND. you can't sample audio with an esp8266, you know that right?

Comment: @dandavis "*you can't sample audio with an esp8266*", if you're going to throw around this kind of information, then you better back it up, everyone will be asking "*And why is that?*". So I'll be the first one to ask. And why is that?

Comment: aside from the too-limited sample rate of the non-differential ADC, continuous processing crashes it due to the wifi WDT.

Comment: Yes I know about the low sample rate at ESP8266 but with combination with MSGEQ7 for the graphic equalizer is almost suficient. [Graphic equalizer](http://www.whatimade.today/graphic-equalizer-using-esp8266-msgeq7-ws2812/) My idea was to use faster ESP32 for FFT analysis without the MSGEQ7. I hoped that ESP32 is much more faster with better ADC sample rate and fast FFT computing. Is there any possibility to make precise beat detection with ESP32? Maybe some ADC module with I2S interface?

Comment: @LX_VSS, the ADC of the ESP32 only works up to [9600 samples per second](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/217) (I think, there's a person responding with a shitty answer). This means that if you sample as often as you can, then you can only see frequencies up to the Nyquist frequency, which is 4800 Hz in this case. The Audio will be going from 20 Hz to ~22 kHz. This means that you will miss ~75% of the audio information. The ESP32 is *not* the right instrument for this.

Comment: and that 32's rate is 10X higher than the 8266's rate

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for sharing your information, I had no idea that the ESP series had... somewhat awful analog handling.